# open() on devices doesn't work on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, file-io

I open disks on Mac using this sort of call open("/dev/disk1", O_RDONLY). But this is failing, return -1 on Mountain Lion.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Have you tried checking `errno`?

Comment: Gatekeeper/entitlements/seat belt?